# CSS Conflict Between 2 Scripts

Tags: html, css

I have a default page CSS, and a table CSS, and I want the table to be correctly displayed, there is a conflict between the CSS. I've identified it but can't solve it.

This is the code that causes the table to look from:

How it should:

[image]

To how it actually shows:

[image]

Main code which causes conflict with table code:

```
*,*:after,*:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;
```

The last part: `box-sizing:border-box;`

And that code is needed for the website to show correctly, so can someone help me?

Comment: How about providing your other code?

Answer (score 0):

Using the * selector is usually frowned on, but you could tack a !important on that to make it work.

```
box-sizing:border-box !important;
```

Comment: Agreed, I won't even answer this question now.